# Facebook API - How to get user's has a verified phone number?

Tags: facebook

I'd like get a boolean value contain the verified phone number status.
I think this information is not mandatory.
If the user not set a phone number the value is FALSE
If the user set some phone number but not verified one then value is FALSE
If the user set some (or one) phone number and there are one is verified then value is TRUE

Has anyone a solution? 
Or are there a different provider who give this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/ the field `verified` contains the info:

> Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions:
>   - Register for mobile
>   - Confirm their account via SMS
>   - Enter a valid credit card

Comment: Thanks, I missed this field. This field is quite correct for me. :)